# search for <b> tags, returns None

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Interesting how BeautifulSoup can't find b tags. Here is HTML:

```
<div id="data_2014-06-12" class="dates">

    <b>

        Ketvirtadienis, birželio 12 d.

    </b>

</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
date = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "dates"})
for i in date:
    print i.find('b')
```

Here is output:

```
None
```

I already searched themes with the same problem, but I couldn't find the right answer why this code returns none.

EDIT:

Here is my full code:

```
from collections import namedtuple
url ="http://www.eurofootball.lt/tvarkarastis"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
date = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "dates"})
for i in date:
    print i.find('b')
```

Here is full div:

div id="data_2014-06-12" class="dates">

```
<b>

    Ketvirtadienis, birželio 12 d.

</b>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: What is the original URL? How are you loading the HTML into BeautifulSoup? It could be the HTML is broken (at which point different parsers will repair the tags differently) or you are using `lxml` and your `libxml2` library is a broken version, or you are passing in a Unicode string instead of a bytestring.

Comment: The sample you have produced here *works* however. There is more to this problem than you posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
Validating the original HTML brings an error to light that is likely responsible for the issue you are observing: `Error Line 573, Column 79: End tag b violates nesting rules. …-12">Ketvirtadienis, birželio 12 d.</b><ul><li class="match_row match_row_leag…`

By the way, the canonical tool for website validation the the W3C validator. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eurofootball.lt%2Ftvarkarastis&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Your code in works, given valid HTML input. This is a complete minimal example:

HTML source code in file `data`:

```
$ cat data
<div id="data_2014-06-12" class="dates">
   <b>Ketvirtadienis, birželio 12 d.</b>
</div>
```

Python test script:

```
$ cat test.py 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = open("data").read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
dates = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "dates"})
for i in dates:
    print i.find('b')
```

Execution:

```
$ python test.py 
<b>Ketvirtadienis, birželio 12 d.</b>
```

I am sure that if you had tried to show a complete minimal example for your case, you would have identified your problem.

Comment: I wanted to find a subtle way for expressing how important creation of a complete example is. I agree and vote for closing.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load [**broken** HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eurofootball.lt%2Ftvarkarastis); how a HTML parser repairs this is not defined by any standard and thus depends on the exact parser you use.

BeautifulSoup supports [different parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser), and each will try to repair the HTML as best they can:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = requests.get("http://www.eurofootball.lt/tvarkarastis").content
>>> [div.b for div in BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').select('div.dates')]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> [div.b for div in BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml').select('div.dates')]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> [div.b for div in BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib').select('div.dates')]
[<b>Ketvirtadienis, birželio 12 d.</b>]
```

Only the `html5lib` parser finds **one** matching bold tag; the other two parsers have omitted the broken `<b>` tag altogether.

That's because the `<div>` tag inside the `<b>` tag is not closed:

```
<b><div class="dates" id="data_2014-06-26">Ketvirtadienis, birželio 26 d.</b>
```

Depending on what parser you are using, just ignore the `<b>` tag altogether; the `html.parser` and `lxml` options see the `<b>` tag as the *parent* tag:

```
>>> [div.parent.name for div in BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').select('div.dates')]
[u'b', u'b', u'b', u'b', u'b', u'b', u'b', u'b', u'b', u'b', u'b', u'b', u'b', u'b', u'b']
```

and you can just grab the text straight out of the `<div>` instead:

```
>>> [div.string for div in BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').select('div.dates')]
[u'Ketvirtadienis, bir\u017eelio 12 d.', u'Penktadienis, bir\u017eelio 13 d.', u'\u0160e\u0161tadienis, bir\u017eelio 14 d.', u'Sekmadienis, bir\u017eelio 15 d.', u'Pirmadienis, bir\u017eelio 16 d.', u'Antradienis, bir\u017eelio 17 d.', u'Tre\u010diadienis, bir\u017eelio 18 d.', u'Ketvirtadienis, bir\u017eelio 19 d.', u'Penktadienis, bir\u017eelio 20 d.', u'\u0160e\u0161tadienis, bir\u017eelio 21 d.', u'Sekmadienis, bir\u017eelio 22 d.', u'Pirmadienis, bir\u017eelio 23 d.', u'Antradienis, bir\u017eelio 24 d.', u'Tre\u010diadienis, bir\u017eelio 25 d.', u'Ketvirtadienis, bir\u017eelio 26 d.']
```